# Typescript interface Set

Tags: typescript

While reading one of angular repo file (link noted below), interface attribute type has **`Set`** method like this;

```
interface testInterface {
  attribute: Set<anotherInterface>;
}
```

What is this this usage can anyone explain?

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/api.ts

Comment: It's a type with one property named `attribute` of `Set<anotherInterface>` type, where `Set` is a built-in ES2015 type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: thank you I didnt notice it was native Set